# Error running /usr/bin/pdflatex (exit code 127)

Tags: r, knitr, pdflatex

I'm running R on Manjaro Linux using R. I installed the R package 'knitr' and it has failed to produce the pdf file.
The error reads:

> Error running /usr/bin/pdflatex (exit code 127)

The *.tex file is created. If I run pdflatex on that file from the command line the pdf is also created.

Any ideas on how to solve this issue?

Comment: Is pdflatex in the path /usr/bin? What do you get when you type `which pdflatex` at the command line?

Comment: @tmpname12345 yes, pdflatex is in the path /usr/bin, although it's shown as 'pdflatex@'
the output for `which pdflatex` is:
/usr/local/texlive/2014/bin/x86_64-linux/pdflatex

Comment: @tmpname12345 I tried to create a symbolic link as explained [here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/kile-can't-find-pdflatex-etc-as-user-875383/) but I get an error 'ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘/usr/bin/pdflatex’: File exists'

Comment: It might be a permissions issue. Sorry I can't be more help than that.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help! I'll check your suggestion about permission issues.

Comment: After checking Rstudio session log I found this:
Error probing for latex version: /usr/bin/pdflatex: error while loading shared libraries: libpoppler.so.48: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory|||
so I decided to run `sudo pacman -Syu` to resolve any existing library conflicts and that made the trick for me.